# What is the ServerIP env variable in docker hub's pihole/pihole used for?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm testing this image for work: https://hub.docker.com/r/pihole/pihole/

It has a mandatory env variable that must be set to the docker host's IP: $ServerIP.

The only explanation it offers for why it must be set is: "to block ads fully".

Setting it seems to change the IP that shows up in PiHole's web interface under `Settings --> System --> Pi-hole IPv4 address`.

I tried setting the env variable to an arbitrary IP (1.1.1.1), and as far as I can tell, nothing broke - the web interface still starts up fine, and the dns server still resolves DNS queries fine.

What exactly does this variable do? It must be important, since it's mandatory.

My biggest concern is that my pi-hole is started using a docker-compose.yml file, and I don't want to hard-code the docker host IP into the docker-compose.yml file in case that IP ever changes.

Update: Upon further research, it appears that pihole can run in several modes. The latest version defaults to `BLOCKINGMODE=NULL`, where `0.0.0.0` is returned to DNS queries. If you put it in `BLOCKINGMODE=IP`, it returns the `Pi-hole IPv4 address` in response to DNS queries. Can anyone confirm that this is the only thing the setting is used for?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the IP address is used to redirect the domain pi.hole to the web interface and to show an info in the position of blocked ads (something like "this has been blocked by pi-hole"). The IP is needed to redirect the blocked domains to the own server.